# How to write selector method for DatePicker DONE button in swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, uidatepicker

While am run the code not showing any error but in console it showes

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[MapSample.SampleViewController dateTextField:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance

Here i have taken textfield in storyboard and i have writen code like below.Help me in the error

```
import UIKit

class SampleViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var dateTextField: UITextField!
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.creatDatePickerView()

    }

    func creatDatePickerView(){

        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
               let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(donePicker))
        toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)

        dateTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        dateTextField.inputView = datePicker

    }


    func donePicker()
    {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
        dateTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        print("done pressed")

    }

}
```

Comment: I looks like the dateTextField is not connected in Storyboard. Is the app also crashing when you try to set a text for your textfield in viewDidLoad?

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs no i hav connected textfield in storyboard. I got message as unrecognised selector to instance, is there any mistake in   this line.             let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(donePicker))

Comment: try #selector(self.donePicker)

Comment: Normally your error says that there is no function dateTextField: in SampleViewController. This is weird and I think it is not about this line.

Comment: yeah i tried but same error

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs thank you now its working, actually dateTextField was connected to one more deligate

Comment: so it was about storyboard connection and not in this line ;)

Comment: Yes dateTextField was connected with two delegates